# I'm trying to use sql command on Python 3.51 and dbf 0.96.005 (for VFP). it have error

Tags: python, visual-foxpro, dbf

```
import dbf
table = dbf.Table('C:/test/MAS.DBF')
table.open()
records = table.sql("select * where SUPCOD = 1.YATHAI")
```

which gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    records = table.sql("select * where SUPCOD = 1.YATHAI")
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\dbf\ver_33.py", line 4637, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'VfpTable' object has no attribute '(supcod = column, 1.YATHAI = value in condition )
```

I need to make the program read data from vfp and insert into PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

For some examples of `dbf` and `sql` (called `pql` in the `dbf` module as it is not full sql syntax) check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6709736/208880).

I suspect your immediate problem will by fixed by adding quotes around the value you want to match and doubling the equal sign (it's really Python syntax):

```
records = table.sql("select * where SUPCOD == '1.YATHAI'")
```

Comment: I see http://pythonhosted.org/dbf/dbf-pysrc.html have sql functions but in Source dbf-0.96.005.zip not have sql functions

Comment: @vetara:  My apologies: at one point I thought having separate code bases for different Python versions would be a good thing, and the `pql` function didn't make it into all three.

Comment: Please advise me for use pql functions  in  dbf_ver33_py

Comment: Download the [newest version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf) which has the `pql` functions restored.